# Foreach loop with in_array() Not Working

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting an in_array() to work. The in_array() is returning false thus the array_push is not being called. I cannot figure out why. The $zipsArray and $propsArray both have data and I have confirmed that there are matching zips in each array. I have also confirmed that each $val has a value.

Help is much appreciated!

---

```
        $zipsArray = self::getZipRadius('vhdf',100);

        $propsArray = self::allProps($dbc,$source);

        $localArray = array();

        foreach($propsArray as $key => $val){

            if(in_array($val['zip'], $zipsArray, true)) {

                $propitem = array(
                    'propid'    => $val['propid'],
                    'street'    => $val['street'],
                    'city'      => $val['city'],
                    'state'     => $val['state'],
                    'zip'       => $val['zip'],
                    'beds'      => $val['beds'],
                    'baths'     => $val['baths'],
                    'garage'    => $val['garage'],
                    'type'      => $val['type'],
                    'sqft'      => str_replace(array('.', ','), '' , $val['sqft']),
                    'descript'  => self::clearString($val['descript']),
                    'listdate'  => $val['listdate'],
                    'askprice'  => $val['askprice'],
                    'repairval' => $val['repairval'],
                    'source'    => $val['source']
                );

                array_push($localArray, $propitem);

            }   

        }

        return $localArray;
```

---

The $zipsArray currently has this data. I shortened it a bit to save scrolling as it currently holds 622 items.

array(1853) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12723"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "12736"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "12736"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "12741"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "12745"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "12760"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "12766"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "12767"
  [8]=>
  string(5) "13020"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [10]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [11]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [12]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [13]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [14]=>
  string(5) "13021"
  [15]=>
  string(5) "13022"
  [16]=>
  string(5) "13026"
  [17]=>
  string(5) "13026"
  [18]=>
  string(5) "13027"
  [19]=>
  string(5) "13027"
  [20]=>
  string(5) "13027"
  [21]=>
  string(5) "13027"
  [22]=>
  string(5) "13027"
  [23]=>
  string(5) "13028"
  [24]=>
  string(5) "13029"
  [25]=>
  string(5) "13030"
  [26]=>
  string(5) "13031"
  [27]=>
  string(5) "13031"
  [28]=>
  string(5) "13031"
  [29]=>
  string(5) "13032"
  [30]=>
  string(5) "13032"
  [31]=>
  string(5) "13032"
  [32]=>
  string(5) "13032"
  [33]=>
  string(5) "13033"
  [34]=>
  string(5) "13034"
  [35]=>
  string(5) "13035"
  [36]=>
  string(5) "13035"
  [37]=>
  string(5) "13035"
  [38]=>
  string(5) "13035"
  [39]=>
  string(5) "13036"
  [40]=>
}

An example of $val is

```
[52]=>
  array(15) {
    ["propid"]=>
    string(6) "274672"
    ["street"]=>
    string(10) "320 Easton"
    ["city"]=>
    string(5) "Depew"
    ["state"]=>
    string(2) "NY"
    ["zip"]=>
    string(5) "14043"
    ["beds"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["baths"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["garage"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["type"]=>
    string(13) "Single Family"
    ["sqft"]=>
    string(3) "972"
    ["descript"]=>
    string(365) "This 972 square foot single family home has 2 bedrooms and 1.0 bathrooms. Located in a desirable part of Depew, property has a lot to offer besides the location in a quite neighborhood it includes a nice size back yard, small front yard for easy maintenance. Just off of a main road close to amenities. 

This Discounted property wont last long contact today."
    ["listdate"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-13"
    ["askprice"]=>
    string(5) "25000"
    ["repairval"]=>
    string(6) "75,000"
    ["source"]=>
    string(4) "prop"
  }
```

Debug reults from in_array():

```
string(5) "33511" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "33442" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "33322" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32258" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32220" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34759" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38106" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32835" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38128" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "64256" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34797" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "87108" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32205" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "04038" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "30273" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32208" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "28304" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "06710" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "46970" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "07107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32922" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32922" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32828" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34748" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32114" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34769" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "76111" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38128" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "77091" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32204" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32208" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32208" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32204" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32217" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32206" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "28301" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32736" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "91706" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38109" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "30315" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "30331" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "28301" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "30318" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "14043" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "30344" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32168" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "33881" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34748" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32137" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "73110" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "33844" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "44118" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60409" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "83634" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "87107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32810" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60633" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32216" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "32725" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60643" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "85123" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "51501" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60827" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "37404" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "19140" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "14131" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "19082" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60426" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "48209" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "18337" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60639" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "48198" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60827" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "49648" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(4) "6610" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "47512" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "23607" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "13205" bool(true) bool(true) int(530) string(5) "32539" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "62206" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "38107" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "44125" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "37921" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "44120" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "40845" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "34420" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "43725" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "44052" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "36701" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "45504" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "35206" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "48205" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "48458" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "64492" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "99999" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60653" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "64130" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "26003" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "47807" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "39212" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "63118" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "20621" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "77830" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "51652" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "27530" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "48089" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "60651" bool(false) bool(false) int(530) string(5) "63135" bool(false) bool(false) int(530)
```

Comment: `in_array()` doesn't appear anywhere in your code but you're asking a question about it. What does it have to do with your problem? Also, show us a sample `$val` whose zip should be found but is not

Comment: Sorry about that. The array_search was an in_array. I was experimenting with no result. I have added the example of $val so you can see it. That $val example is one of the zips in the $zipsArray. Like I had said I shortened it to help with scrolling.

Comment: Why does your example of `$val` have `[52]` near the top? Would you add something like `if($key===0) var_dump($val)` immediately under the `foreach` line so we can see a single `$val` with nothing around it.

Comment: That is copied from a dumped <pre></pre> which ads counts and all that

Comment: If you dump just `$val` itself, it won't look like that. The first line will be the data type (eg: `Array`), not an index number such as `[52]`.  What you posted was probably just a portion from a greater var dump

Comment: First, I assume you want to return the `$localArray` as you already have the $zipsArray? Whatever, debugging - I would do: `var_dump($val['zip'], in_array($val['zip'], $zipsArray, true), in_array($val['zip'], $zipsArray), __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately before and after the 'if` statement. Why? it will tell me what the values are and the results of the tests using `strict` and 'juggling'. I would be able to see ('a zip value', true, true). It will take   less than five minutes to do this and you will see what is happening.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to have the root file path in there so I removed that and did the dump... After discovering that is is returning true results I dumped $propitem.... I discovered that it is returning a result...

So what's actually not working is the array_push() and not the in_array(). So in otherwords $propitem is not being pushed into $localArray so $localArray is returning empty.

I have added the results of Ryan's debug to the original post.

Comment: in_array() is returning array(15) { ["propid"]=> string(2) "73" ["street"]=> string(13) "150 W Corning" ["city"]=> string(8) "Syracuse" ["state"]=> string(2) "NY" ["zip"]=> string(5) "13205" ["beds"]=> string(1) "0" ["baths"]=> string(1) "0" ["garage"]=> string(1) "0" ["type"]=> string(11) "Vacant Land" ["sqft"]=> string(1) "0" ["descript"]=> string(61) "3,168 Sqft Lot; buyer responsible for ~$9k in deliquent taxes" ["listdate"]=> string(19) "2016-07-13 14:48:25" ["askprice"]=> string(3) "500" ["repairval"]=> string(3) "500" ["source"]=> string(3) "reo" } int(534)

Comment: Yes they are, there is one. The if state IS returning a result. What I have discovered is the array_push is what is not working. Therefor the $localArray is returning empty which it should not be, as it should have one result.

Comment: I did that already. The $propitem is returning a result but $localArray is still empty after the array_push. The value of $propitem is the dump in the comment I posted a few comments ago.

Answer (score 0):

If the third parameter strict of in_array is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

**Remove the strict mode** (third_parameter) **or make sure both arrays contains zip codes as string** (The second is more fool proof). Debug data shows one of the arrays containing zip codes as a string while the other contains it as an integer.